# How can I add a custom mimetype for rendering in jupyterlab?

Tags: reactjs, ipython, jupyter-lab

I have some python calculations which are being done and all the data is being stored as possibly a json or a string object.
I would like to create a custom renderer for this, such that it reads this json object and renders a react widget.
How can I do the same?
For example I have:

[image: Some simple data]

So that when the reply comes from python, I would like to render the `content.data` as `react-widget` rather than `text/plain`

[image: Kernel Spy]